# AutoCompleteTextView in action bar not working?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, autocompletetextview

I am trying to use an auto complete text view in the action bar. Though I am able to put the auto complete action view there, whenever I start typing, I do not see a drop down with recommendations. It acts like a normal edit text box.

Then, just for testing, I included an auto complete text view in the app layout as well. But this one works exactly like it is supposed to. 
Both of the auto complete text views were initialized using the same adapter.

**This is the main activity's onCreate method.**

```
//defining an array to be used by the array adapters

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;

private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] { "Belgium",
    "France", "France_", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain" };

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //inflating the activity layout
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.frag_map);

    //getting the action bar
    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.map_screen_ab_auto_commplete);
    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.map_screen_ab_auto_commplete, null);

    //Defining an adapter which will then be used by auto complete text view
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);

    //setting an auto complete text view in the action bar.PLEASE NOTE THAT THIS DOES NOT WORK
        mAutocompleteView = (AutoCompleteTextView) v
        .findViewById(R.id.map_screen_auto_complete);
    mAutocompleteView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //just for checking, another auto complete text view was added. THIS WORKS
    test_ac_view = (AutoCompleteTextView) this.findViewById(R.id.test_ac_view);
    test_ac_view.setAdapter( adapter);
}
```

**This is the main activity layout that also conatins an auto complete text view:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New AutoCompleteTextView"
        android:id="@+id/test_ac_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

**This is the layout for action bar that contains the auto complete text view.**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/map_screen_auto_complete"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Search Location" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: where are you defining `test_ac_view`

Answer (score 0):

In the Manifest file make sure that AppTheme is this :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you set adapter to `AutoCompleteTextView` which was created with the Inflator. But you ActionBar uses another one created from R.layout.layout_id which was provided in `setCustomView` method.

Try to do this:

```
LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.map_screen_ab_auto_commplete, null);
actionBar.setCustomView(v);
```

instead of `actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.map_screen_ab_auto_commplete);`